# Python-Pandas: How to create a sort Dataframe through how many similar values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just starting to learn programming, so I took this online Intro to Python workshop from General Assembly.

We were given this [task](https://github.com/kasun-maldeni/intro-to-python) to complete. I've done 1, 2, 3, and 4.

I'm having difficulty with 5. To be honest, I don't even know what to look for.

I've tried using the Pandas documentation website, [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/), and 
[Data To Fish](https://datatofish.com/sort-pandas-dataframe/). However, I don't think these will help with what I really need to do.

Here's my [solution](https://gist.github.com/rshdschwdhry/1d98111a42afa5ef79d63c6001cfffa7).

Here's a link to my question in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/dly752/pythonpandas_how_to_create_a_sort_dataframe_thru/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

Thanks.

Comment: Hint, first step is: `df.groupby('Subjects', as_index=False)['Name'].agg(" and ".join)`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kasun-maldeni/intro-to-python/master/data.csv")
```

---

```
print(data)
      name     location   subjects
0     todd    melbourne    physics
1    jamie      toronto    physics
2  rebecca  Los Angeles      maths
3  michael       Sydney    biology
4  vincent      toronto  chemistry
5  georgia    Melbourne      stats
6    allen      toronto  chemistry
7    sarah     auckland  chemistry
```

You can use [`Series.str.title`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html) first for first letters uppercase with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html).

```
data = data.assign(name= data['name'].str.title(), subjects= data['subjects'].str.title())
```

Then aggregate with `join` and if not necessary distiguish between plural and singular use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
s = data.groupby('subjects')['name'].agg(" and ".join)
out1 = s.str.cat(s.index, sep=' are taking ').tolist()
print (out1)
['Michael are taking Biology', 'Vincent and Allen and Sarah are taking Chemistry',
 'Rebecca are taking Maths', 'Todd and Jamie are taking Physics', 'Georgia are taking Stats
```

Another solution is possible aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count:

```
data = data.assign(name= data['name'].str.title(), subjects= data['subjects'].str.title())
df1 = data.groupby('subjects')['name'].agg([" and ".join, 'size'])
print (df1)
                                  join  size
subjects                                    
Biology                        Michael     1
Chemistry  Vincent and Allen and Sarah     3
Maths                          Rebecca     1
Physics                 Todd and Jamie     2
Stats                          Georgia     1
```

So is possible create array of separators with compare by condition by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and join together with `+`:

```
sep = np.where(df1['size'] == 1, ' is taking ', ' are taking ')
out2 = (df1['join'] + sep + df1.index).tolist()
print (out2)
['Michael is taking Biology', 'Vincent and Allen and Sarah are taking Chemistry', 
 'Rebecca is taking Maths', 'Todd and Jamie are taking Physics', 'Georgia is taking Stats']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should be to group the students by the subjects:

```
>>> agg_df = data.groupby("subjects", as_index=False)["name"].agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
>>> print(agg_df)
    subjects                     name
0    biology                [michael]
1  chemistry  [vincent, allen, sarah]
2      maths                [rebecca]
3    physics            [todd, jamie]
4      stats                [georgia]
```

Then you can loop over the rows to make the sentences and append them to a list:

```
ls1 = []

for i, row in agg_df.iterrows():
    str1 = " and ".join(row['name']) + (" are" if len(row['name']) > 1 else " is") + " taking {0}".format(row['subjects'])
    ls1.append(str1)

print(". ".join(ls1))
# 'michael are taking biology. vincent and allen and sarah are taking chemistry. rebecca are taking maths. todd and jamie are taking physics. georgia are taking stats'
```

Comment: @jezrael OP has just begun python coding. Explanation is very important as well